# Word Interop and Iterating through Shape Objects to find textbox

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm attempting to iterate through a word document and its shape objects to find DOCVARIABLES. The shape object has a textbox. Here's the macros I'm pulling directly from Word.

> Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 7")).Select

The textbox is in a shape object that's contained in the headerfooter. I've iterated shape range for both header and footer, but I only retrieved **shapeRange[j].Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject** :

```
foreach (HeaderFooter footer in section.Footers)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= footer.Shapes.Count; i++)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ShapeRange shapeRange = footer.Shapes.Range(i);
        for (int j = 1; j <= shapeRange.Count; j++)
        {
            string shapetype = shapeRange[j].Name;
            if (shapeRange[j].Type == MsoShapeType.msoTextBox)
            {
                var shapeFields = shapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                if (shapeFields.Contains("DOCVARIABLE"))
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify what *kind* of "textbox" is involved. There are numerous things in Word that are (or can be called) "textbox". Each needs to be handled differently in code. If you don't know the technical term, describe the commands to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by @slightlysnarky - verifying that TextFrame.HasText is true.

Done for both header and footer.

```
foreach (Shape objShape in header.Shapes)
{
    if (objShape.TextFrame.HasText != 0)
    {
        foreach (Field objField in objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields)
            {
```